# define a const char* in cython

Tags: python, c++, pointers, ctypes

I want to call following function from a dll in Python with ctypes:

```
int PI_EnumerateUSB (char* szBuffer, int iBufferSize, const char* szFilter)
```

Which variable do I have to define for `const char* szFilter`?
I tried following:

```
ch_szFilter = c_char_p("C-863")
p_ch_szFilter = address(ch_szFilter)
```

Here `p_ch_stFilter` should be my `const char* szFilter` but it doesn't work. 
I get following error message:

```
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (12 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

I don't have much experience with Python an it's my first project with ctypes.

Comment: You have the wrong [x86 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).  Load the DLL using `ctypes.WinDLL`, which uses `stdcall` (callee cleanup), as opposed to `cdecl` (caller cleanup).

Comment: The first parameter needs to be a writable buffer, e.g. `szBuffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(iBufferSize)`. For the filter just use `szFilter = b'C-863'`. This is safe because it's a `const char *` parameter.

Comment: Thank you. How can I use `szFilter = b'C-863'` ? I think it has to be a pointer, too?!

Comment: ctypes passes a pointer to the string's internal buffer. This is fine given the parameter is a `const char *`.

Comment: Maybe I will read something about that. It didn't work until now.